# How to get data as a Map<String, List<String>> using a single query?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, collections

How to get data as a `Map<String, List<String>>` using a single query?
I have table **filters:**

```
|id|filter_name|filter_code| keyword|
------------------------------------
|1 |  banana   |    237    |category|
|2 |   apple   |    250    |category|
|3 |   water   |    320    |category|
|4 |   owner   |    4410   | param  |
|5 |   place   |    5389   | param  |
```

So, I need to get *keyword* like a key and *filter_code* like a list of values.
Income data: **id** and **keyword**
Edited: In the output, I need to get `Map<keyword, List<filter_code>>`. All params are strings

Comment: Please add expected output to better explain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```java
static Map<String, List<String>> read() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONSTR);
        PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(
            "select keyword, filter_code from filters");
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery()) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        while (rs.next())
            map.computeIfAbsent(rs.getString(1), k -> new ArrayList<>())
                .add(rs.getString(2));
        return map;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = read();
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output:

```json
{category=[237, 250, 320], param=[4410, 5389]}
```